# EloquentJavascript: reverseArrayInPlace function. Is this an acceptable code or would this be considered poor logic?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, reverse

The exercise asks to create a function, reverseArrayInPlace(), that takes an existing array and reverses its order by only using the existing array. The exercise also advises that I cannot use the reverse method for an array.

```
var arrayValue = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
reverseArrayInPlace(arrayValue);
console.log(arrayValue);
// → [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

This is the solution that I came up with:

```js
var arrayValue = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    
    function reverseArrayInPlace(inputArray){
      for (let i = inputArray.length - 2; i >= 0; i--){
        inputArray.push(inputArray[i]);
      }
      inputArray.splice(0, inputArray.length / 2);
    }
    
    reverseArrayInPlace(arrayValue);
    console.log(arrayValue);
```

Although it solves the problem posed, I want to ensure that I am not developing bad habits and that this is an acceptable solution. Would there be a more ideal way to solve this problem?

Comment: Thanks! I have never seen a two-variable for loop used before... that is an awesome solution!